# How to assign the caps lock key to right-click in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In my opinion this is the best use for the otherwise completely useless caps lock key (in my opinion). How can it be done in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

It does not seem like there is any way to *transparently* remap keyboard events into mouse events.

But, you can make it work *almost* the same. Install [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), and add following keyboard mapping:

```
Special: Capslock (00_3A) => Special: Application (E0_5D)
```

(you will need to logoff and logon again).
This will make Capslock to work the same as right Menu key, which for most intents and purposes does the same job as mouse right click, or calling object properties.